# Examples of Gorenstein local unique factorization domain of dimension $2$ and embedding dimension $4$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, local-rings, gorenstein

I am looking for an example of a local UFD $(R,\mathfrak m)$ of dimension $2$ which is also Gorenstein and $\mathfrak m$ is minimally generated by four elements. Does there exist any such examples?

Comment: You can replace the "Gorenstein" hypothesis with "Cohen-Macaulay complete", since the canonical module (if it exists) always represents a divisor class, hence is trivial for a UFD

Comment: @math54321: I know that... how does that help me in finding examples?